# Any resources on building a scalable front-end architecture?

Tags: architecture, web, frontend

I'm gonna create a whole new website and write everything from scratch, mostly on front-end part. I just wanna know if there is any resources on building a scalable front-end architecture cause I never had this kind of experience before. Any suggestion, idea or book recommendation would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Scalable front-end? Usually front ends (i am referring to a client here..for e.g. a browser) don't have to scale beyond 1 user. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: What I really mean is that as I need to write a lot of javascript files, how to structure these js files in a large website?

Comment: If you are planning on using a framework (which I would recommend if you weren't planning on) on the client side, then its just a matter of searching on the interwebs for what people have done. For e.g. For AngularJS, the seed app template (https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) works well. If you are not using a framework, then its going to be impossible to answer your question, because its going to depend on how you are going to architect you front-end (mvc, mvvm etc).

Comment: “Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.” [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I don't think there is an exact definition of what you or everyone else mean about scalable front-end, and because of that, it is hard to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to answer your question, because we are unsure every part of it. As far as I know there is no such definition as *"scalable front-end architecture"*. Both *scalable* and *front-end* are very wide topics, so I can only guess...

I assume in your terms the *front-end* means *single page javascript applications* and the *scalable* part means *functional scalability* (not *load scalability* as usually used in a server side context). With these constraints I think the REST architecture is the best match I know.

- By the REST architecture there are REST services and REST clients. Both are applications. You can run a REST client in your browser as front-end application and you can run a REST service on your server as back-end application. REST is designed for HTTP 1.1 protocol, so as you see it can easily fit in the usual context of HTTP client and server.
- A regular web service provides only data to its clients (for example in JSON format), and the clients should know what to do with it. So the clients must contain fragments of business logic. The service contains business logic as well, because it is the only safe environment to check request validity and because only it has access to a common persistent storage (database). So in that case both the service and the client contains the same code fragments, and because of that, the code of the web application is not DRY. I guess you already know that non DRY code is hard to maintain... By REST architecture the service sends not just data, but the representation of abstract controllers (links and forms) to the clients. This can be done by sending any hypermedia format. If you think about the HTTP communication does the same, it sends controller and data representations in a HTML format. We could use HTML as a message format but it is not recommended, because parsing it is hard and slow, and there aren't any recommendations how to serialize data in a HTML format. XML and JSON are different, they are designed for data serialization, but they have a lack of controller description. Currently there are many new born hypermedia formats built on XML and JSON, which are capable of that: ATOM+XML, HAL+XML, HAL+JSON, JSON-LD, siren (JSON), collection+JSON, etc...
- So your REST client gets data and controller representation in a hypermedia format from the REST service. For example by a profile page you get a name a birth date, etc... as data and an edit form, a delete link, etc... as controllers. Currently there are very few standards/recommendations how to describe the controllers. You can learn the media types I mentioned or make an own media type. It is not so hard... What counts, that the REST client should not know anything about the exact controllers until it gets them. It can know only about how to display a controller it gets from the service. For example by a registration form it should not know the url the method, the name of the input fields, etc... but it must know how to display a registration form described in the current hypermedia format. The browsers does the same, they get forms as HTML FORM elements, and displays them very well despite the fact they know nothing about what will happen when they send the filled forms back to the server. So browsers does know nothing about the business logic of the web applications they are displaying. REST clients do the same with REST services, they know nothing about the business logic of the REST services, they just know how to display the hypermedia the REST service sends back, and how to send a request to the service. It is an easy understandable approach I think... Because of this design approach the REST clients and the REST services are loose coupled, error tolerant and easy maintainable. For example if you add a new feature to your REST service for example a new link, it usually does not affect your REST clients because they are already prepared to handling links...

I think it is pretty easy to understand the theory of the REST architecture, however the know-how is much more difficult. It causes a lot of confusion that people often call their regular web service a REST service, because REST architecture is a hype nowadays. Everyone wants to do it, but very few of them do it right...